# How make ooma work with Sophos UTM

Tags: filtering, voip, virus-scanning

I recently installed a Sophos UTM Home firewall at my home. It seems very full featured and powerful. However, my ooma device stopped working when I set it up. During setup of the Sophos box I told it to allow Voip communications as can be seen from the screen capture. Here is what my network looks like:

10.0.0.0/24 network --> Cisco Router --> Sophos --> ISP

My internal network is a 10.0.0.0/24 network. The Sophos box is address 10.1.1.1 and the Cisco router has a static IP of 10.1.1.2. Sophos is configured to consider any "10" address to be internal (i.e. 10.0.0.0/8). Web browsing works fine, so I know I'm connected to Internet. However, for some reason it is blocking my Ooma device.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Have you explicitely allowed the ports used by Ooma, as these are not on the standard "VOIP" ports?

It looks like you haven't.